# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConexionBBDD'

Tags: mysql, python

mi problema es el siguiente. **No puedo importar el paquete `ConexionBBDD` desde mi paquete `Cliente,`** como podria solucionarlo? 
Ya tengo dentro del paquete un archivo `__init__.py` vacio, pero al llamarlo no me lo reconoce como paquete, que estoy haciendo mal?

Paquete desde el cual quiero llamar mi paquete de `conexionBBDD`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Tu debes agregar el directorio `Despensa` a tu variable de entorno `PYTHONPATH` para importar el paquete `ConexionBBDD`. Por lo démas, Python no sabe dònde encontrarlo.

Para agregar un directorio a tu variable de entorno `PYTHONPATH` en Windows, tu puedes leer [este pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7) en la versiòn en inglés de StackOverflow.